# The maximum of $\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

The following question comes from an American Olympiad problem. The reason why I am posting it here is that, although it seems really easy, it allows for some different and really interesting solutions. Do you want to give a try?

Let $n$ be one million. Find the maximum value attained by $\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x}$, where $0<x<n$ is an integer.

---

Edit: I saw the answers below, and I can say that I posted this one because there is at least one really nice solution, which is not so "mechanical" :) The value of $n$ has no particular meaning, it stands just for a "sufficiently large integer"..

Comment: Maple answers $$ { 9.58265829501\cdot 10^{301023}},[x=499499] .$$

Comment: @user64494: Which raises the question what they mean by "find the maximum value"; there seems to be no reasonable way to express more than an approximation of the _value_ (even if $x$ is exact).

Comment: $$\begin{align}n=10^1,\qquad k&=3\\n=10^2,\qquad k&=44\\n=10^3,\qquad k&=484\\n=10^4,\qquad k&=4949\end{align}$$

Comment: For $k \le [n/2]$, $$\left(\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k-1}\right) - \left(\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n}{k-2}\right) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k+2)!}(2k - (n+2+\sqrt{n+2}))(2k-(n+2-\sqrt{n+2}))$$

So, $$\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{k-1} \ge \binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n}{k-2}$$ if $k \le \frac{1}{2}(n+2-\sqrt{n+2})$.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: It is clear that 301023 digits are too many to be displayed.

Comment: @user64494: Or to be computed by hand; that is what my comment was suggesting. I wonder why they did not just ask for the value of $x$, which would have maintained the essence of the challenge.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, The OP could have missed out on the value of x for " Maximum....".  That could be a possibility.

Comment: You are all right in principle; the essence is to find the optimal value $x_0$; nevertheless, one could simply answer $\binom{n}{x_0+1}-\binom{n}{x_0}$, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x},$$ 
then
$$f(x)-f(x-1)=\frac{n!(4x^2-4nx+n^2-n-2)}{(x+1)!(n-x+1)!}$$

The roots of the quadratic are 
$$\frac{n\pm\sqrt{n+2}}{2}$$

Hence $f(x)>f(x-1)$ up to $\frac{n-\sqrt{n+2}}{2}$.

For 
$$x>\frac{n+\sqrt{n+2}}{2}$$

it is clear that $f(x)<0$.

So maximum $f(x)$ at 
$$x=\left\lfloor\frac{n-\sqrt{n+2}}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{1000000-\sqrt{1000002}}{2}\right\rfloor=499499$$

Comment: Amazing solution which kind of happens to be in track with what Scion suggested with ofcourse some modification.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x}
&=\left[\frac{n-x}{x+1}-1\right]\binom{n}{x}\\
&=\frac{n-2x-1}{x+1}\binom{n}{x}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$ is positive for $x\lt\frac{n-1}2$ and negative for $x\gt\frac{n-1}2$.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\hphantom{}\left[\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x}\right]-\left[\binom{n}{x}-\binom{n}{x-1}\right]\\
&=\left(\left[\frac{n-x}{x+1}-1\right]-\left[1-\frac{x}{n-x+1}\right]\right)\binom{n}{x}\\
&=\frac{4x^2-4nx+(n+1)(n-2)}{(x+1)(n-x+1)}\binom{n}{x}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)$ is $0$ when $x=\frac{n\pm\sqrt{n+2}}2$. If this $x$ is an integer, then $\binom{n}{x+1}-\binom{n}{x}=\binom{n}{x}-\binom{n}{x-1}$. Otherwise, the maximum occurs somewhere between $x$ and $x-1$.

Thus, the maximum value for $(1)$ is where $x=\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-\sqrt{n+2}}2\right\rfloor$.

For $n=1000000$, $x=499499$.
$$
\binom{1000000}{499500}-\binom{1000000}{499499}=9.582658295\times10^{301023}
$$
whereas
$$
\binom{1000000}{499499}-\binom{1000000}{499498}=9.582581749\times10^{301023}
$$
and
$$
\binom{1000000}{499501}-\binom{1000000}{499500}=9.582658257\times10^{301023}
$$

Comment: When I posted my answer, I noticed it looked a lot like Kyson's answer. I've added some to my explanation, hopefully, to make it worth undeleting.

Answer (score 3):

$$t_x=\binom n{x+1}-\binom nx=\frac{(n-2x-1)}{(x+1)}\binom nx$$
$$\frac{t_x}{t_{x-1}}=\frac{n-x+1}{(x+1)(n-2x+1)(n-2x)}=z$$
If $z\ge1$:
$$\frac{n-x+1}{(x+1)(n-2x+1)(n-2x)}\ge1\implies x\le z_0(\text{say})$$
Then maximum occurs at :
$$x=\lfloor z_0\rfloor$$